# How to edit a record using Java Servlet in Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

after much research, I was able to insert a record to Google Appengine with the followings below. However, now I've got an issue: I am unable to edit the record using the query following GQL or SQL syntax. Please help!

```
public class AppointmentServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

    Date dateLog = new Date();
    String merchant = req.getParameter("merchant");
    String date = req.getParameter("date");
    String time = req.getParameter("time");
    String strDateTime = date + " " + time;
    Date dateTime = null;
    try {
        dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").parse(strDateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    }
    String service = req.getParameter("service");
    String personnel = "Internet Booking";
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String phone = req.getParameter("phone");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    String request = req.getParameter("request");

    if(email.isEmpty()) {
        email = "-";
    } 

    if(request.isEmpty()) {
        request = "-";
    }

    Appointment appt = new Appointment(dateLog, merchant, dateTime, service, personnel, name, phone, email, request);

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(appt);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

    resp.sendRedirect("/appointment/complete.jsp");
}
```

}

I have a "EDIT" form where any of the field could be edited. So please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think it has something to do with App Engine.
2. You should take a look at various crud examples out there.
3. A simple googling gave  [gave nice results.](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=servlet%20crud&oq=servlet%20crud&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l7j0i22i10i30j0i8.788.1932.1.2168.12.10.0.0.0.0.282.2070.0j6j4.10.0...0.0.0..1c.1.17.hp.nSppp7xxTVg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk&fp=fa8637170e6c6cd8&biw=1366&bih=655)

If you're unable to get the examples, you can post another question here regarding the specific doubt or at the example site.

Comment: Thanks man, the keyword was CRUD! I used it to search and finally got my answer! http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jdo-spring-mvc-crud-example/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code under **Storing data** in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657408/can-i-make-these-method-more-efficient-my-app-seems-to-be-eating-up-a-lot-of-my)